# Is it valid to call a constexpr function in a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compiler-errors, constexpr

```
constexpr int get () { return 5; }
template<int N> struct Test {};

int main ()
{
  int a[get()];  // ok
  Test< get() > obj;  // error:'int get()' cannot appear in a constant-expression
}
```

I have [compiled this code with ideone](http://www.ideone.com/3WkGV). And was wondering that why it's giving compilation error.
Is `constexpr` function not allowed as `template` argument or it's a bug in the compiler ?

**Edit**: changed `const int get()` to `int get()`
Moreover, there is one more *bug* with ideone is that, if you remove `constexpr` then [still declaring an array is allowed](http://www.ideone.com/fYAdT)!! I think that's a C99 feature.

Comment: Your edit is incorrect, you made it `constexpr const get()`.

Comment: On the edit, that is a C99 feature, and gcc has it as an extension, but it is not proper C++, and it will not be portable. It was considered for inclusion in the standard and rejected as it would break the invariant that types (the size is part of the type) must be known at compile time. In C it does not matter that much, but in C++ you would not be able to use that array as a type argument to a template (exact type unknown at compile time) --which is by the way the behavior in gcc, it will complain if you try to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GCC 4.5 (at least the version used at Ideone) does not entirely support `constexpr`, including your valid usage; it waters down to a `const`. GCC 4.6 and up correctly supports it.